# Why a company offers share purchase plan under RRSP but not TFSA?

Tags: canada, employee-stock-options

My company is offering share purchase plans under a tax free umbrella. What this means is that you can use your rrsp limit to contribute to thsi plan and gains will not be taxed unless withdrawn.

My ques is why does not a company use TFSA limit for share purchase plans? Why is it RRSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and most likely, it is simply historical.  RRSPs have been around for many years, while TFSA are new.  Therefore companies have plans in place to deal with them as a benefit to their employees.

Secondly, is the tax sheltering aspect.  Because RRSPs generate a tax refund while TFSA are invested with after-tax cash, companies are more attuned to the pension adjustment aspects of the RRSP refund area than TFSA.